# Carga masiva de datos .txt con C# web a SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, web

I was seeing massive data insertions with C# web with and the data to be extra is EXCEL, I wanted to know how it would be with .txt.

How would it be in web C#?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string conexion = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source=C:\\importar\\Excel_DB.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes\"";
        OleDbConnection origen = default(OleDbConnection);
        origen = new OleDbConnection(conexion);

        OleDbCommand seleccion = default(OleDbCommand);
        seleccion = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [Hoja1$]", origen);

        OleDbDataAdapter adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        adaptador.SelectCommand = seleccion;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adaptador.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        origen.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please try to clarify your question, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Using oledb is the fastest method for storing excel data into a SQL Server.  Putting data into a DGV is not necessary and will slow down the code.  You can use BulkCopy which uses the oledb connection which will speed up the code.

Comment: I want to do that function but with ASP.NET C # and they are data of a .txt, if they have an example or article

Comment: to be more clear, I wanted an example like this but oriented to "txt" files     https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193647/cargar-un-archivo-plano-excel-y-mediante-asp-net-c-un-web-form-cargarlo-y-los